# When will Unique Constraints be supported in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-5, unique-constraint

I just got a rude awakening. EF Associations on Unique Constraints are not supported in EF5.

Some googling on the issue does not turn up much info...

Who can tell me when Unique Constraints will be supported in Entity Framework?

Thanks.

-d

Comment: Vote for this Feature in codeplex

Comment: Most recent statement is probably here (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299) in the comments section: *August, 14 2013: "Note for triage: we discussed recently about trying to at least start this work in the next version."* The next version which can only be meant here is EF 7. So, one *might* guess, in 1 or 2 years - if there weren't words like *"trying"*, *"at least"* and *"start"* in the statement...

Comment: Thanks.  I did find that page.  But it had so little traffic for being a year old, I was hoping there was something more current.  Anyway, I added my two cents on that page.